# VB6 application on Citrix ODBC connection failure

Tags: windows, ms-access, vb6, odbc, citrix

We have a Visual Basic 6 application that connects to a local MS Access mdb file to store some values during work processing. The connection to this file is done via a user DSN ODBC connection. We have determined that the path of the connection is valid. However, occasionally, and at seemingly random times, calls to this mdb file will fail with an ODBC error message that the path is invalid. The path is reported back as "null". At other times, we receive a "disk or network error" message. There does not appear to be any consistency to why or how these errors occur.

Are there any registry or configuration values that we should be looking at to determine the source of this problem? The file is not disappearing from the server at any point, so we are leaning towards the problem being an ODBC configuration.

The VB application is running under Citrix on a Windows 2003 server (32-bit).

Comment: If you are connecting to this Access db over the network then you can be party to a whole host of interesting effects.  Access databases are easily corrupted.  Make sure, after you experience a disconnect like this, that you compact and repair, just in case.

Comment: Actually, the Access database file is on the same device.

Comment: It sounds as if you either have a flaky local drive or else some sort of collision among users trying to delete and recreate this database.  Are you at least creating it in a per-user location such as in the user's profile (LocalAppData)?  Or if not, are you using unique names based on the user name or App.ThreadID or something?

Comment: *Actually, the Access database file is on the same device. – Timbuck* - So are you connecting to the server using a client or are you using the server directly (i.e. keyboard and monitor plugged into the server)?

Comment: We are connecting to the server via a Citrix session from separate devices.The database file is created in the user's profile.

Answer (score 0):

I have received that same error about the null database in a classic VB 6 application but not using DSN and whenever I saw that error it was usually when it was querying a corrupt table.  When was the last time that you compacted and cleaned the database out?

Also, the error combined with disk or network error could have to do with write permissions and citrix, as if it is not able to write out the .ldb file or database lock file.

Have you looked into your event viewer after one of these errors have occurred to see if that would shed some more light on an error happening at the same time?

Comment: To add some information, we do a "kill" of the database file and recreate a new one whenever a user relaunches our application - ostensibly to try and prevent such corruption from occurring (I'm guessing here - the app is 15 years old and I've been here for 5.) The mdb file is a single table with a single row in it, used as scratch space.